# Filtering Pivot table for specific cell values when number of PivotItems vary

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I am working on this Excel VBA script that filters Pivot table with specific values in given Pivot field.

I need this to be more dynamic. Every time my macro filters for something that is not in the current Pivot field, I get error message.

The following filtering code, works when all the .PivotItems are present in the data but this changes from data to data and I cannot type this manually every time to have it the same as in the data:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Dispute ")
        '.PivotItems("CA - Carriage").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("Credit").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("DOC - Documentation issue").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Paid").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Promise to pay").Visible = False
        '.PivotItems("QQ - Quantity Query").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("SR - Sales Related").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("PT - Payment Terms").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("payment in advance").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Bancrupcy").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("PO - Purchase Order").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("RT - Returns").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("to be reconcilied").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Dispute - Resolved").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Follow up ").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("escalation").Visible = False
    End With
```

Lets say ".PivotItems("escalation").Visible = False" is not present in the data this time, the macro then throws error when trying to filter it out.

There should be a solution to just provide ".PivotItems" I want to show in the filter and ignore the rest but so far I could not google exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use an array to store your (un)wanted fileds into and iterate through it:

```
Dim fields As Variant, field As Variant

fields = Array("field1", "field2", "field8")' <-- name of the fields you want to hide
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Dispute ")
    For Each field In fields
        .PivotItems(field).Visible = False
    Next
End With
```

Edit after OP clarifications

or, if you already know the fields you want to be visible:

```
Dim fieldsIWantToShowForSure As Variant
fieldsIWantToShowForSure = Array("field1", "field2", "field8")

Dim pvtIt As PivotItem
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Dispute ")
    For Each pvtIt In .PivotItems
        If IsError(Application.Match(pvtIt.Name, fieldsIWantToShowForSure, 0)) Then pvtIt.Visible = False
    Next
End With
```

Comment: I don't think this will do because the fields I want to hide can be different from data to data. I know for sure only those fields that I want to show as ".Visible=True" and need to hide the rest. Your suggestion seems to me that I would get error again once the data in Dispute filter are not included in the Array and if I include all the data in Array, it will hide everything. I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Well, that was not so clear from your question. See edited answer and if it solves your question you may want to mark it as accepted to direct future readers,… And of you found it useful you may want to upvote it, too. Thanks